# CMake Failed to get Python3_SITELIB

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build the [libArcus](https://github.com/Ultimaker/libArcus) library using CMake. However I'm getting the following error message:

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindSIP.cmake:48 (message):
  Failed to get Python3_SITELIB.  Error:
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package)
```

This is the relevant code in FindSIP.cmake (keep in mind that this is not my code):

```
find_package(PythonInterp 3.5 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.5 REQUIRED)

# Define variables that are available in FindPython3, so there's no need to branch off in the later part.
set(Python3_EXECUTABLE ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE})
set(Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(Python3_LIBRARIES ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
set(Python3_VERSION_MINOR "${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}")

execute_process(
   COMMAND ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} -c
           "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=False,standard_lib=False))"
   RESULT_VARIABLE _process_status
   OUTPUT_VARIABLE _process_output
   OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
if(${_process_status} EQUAL 0)
   string(STRIP ${_process_output} Python3_SITELIB)
else()
   message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to get Python3_SITELIB. Error: ${_process_output}")
endif()
```

I've determined that the `execute_process` command, which is in turn executing python command `import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=False,standard_lib=False))` is somehow failing. I've executed the python command on its own and it works fine, I get the following path: `C:\Users\<Username>\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.2\Lib\site-packages`, which I'm pretty sure is what it is supposed to give. I don't get why this is not working in CMake.

I'm running Windows 10 and I use pyenv to manage python versions, the global version is 3.8.2.